# How to map row data into column wise in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below as input data from back end.
const data=[{id:1,name:"xyz"},{id:2,name:"abc"}]

I need to convert above data into below format.

[id:{1,2},name:{"xyz","abc"]

I want to create a dynamic function that yield above result

Comment: the `[id:{1,2},name:{"xyz","abc"}]` notation to define array is incorrect. the correct one is `[{"id": [1, 2]},{"name": ["xyz", "abc"]}]`

Comment: Your output is invalid. It looks like you want an object.

Comment: yes @AhmadDeel you are right

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow

```
const formattedData = Object.keys(a[0])
.map(key=>{
    let c={};
    c[key] = a.map(d=>d[key])
    return c
})
```

will return

```
[
    {"id": [1, 2]},
    {"name": ["xyz", "abc"]}
]
```